# Add css to head and refresh it dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I try to add a css rule dynamically by javascript and then update css on scroll event.

This is my code:

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        createElement = document.createElement('style');
    // append style to head
    head.appendChild(createElement); 

    // scroll event
    $(window).on('scroll touchmove', function(e) {
        // define variables 
        var body = $('body'),
            style = {
                waY: $(document).scrollTop()
            };
        // create css rules
        var css = 'body:before {';
            css += 'background-position: 0px ' + (style.waY*0.4).toFixed(2) + 'px';
            css += '}';
            css += 'body:after {';
            css += 'background-position: 0px ' + (style.waY*0.4).toFixed(2) + 'px';
            css += '}';

        createElement.innerHTML = '';
        // add css rules to style tag
        if (css.styleSheet) {
            // If IE
            createElement.styleSheet.cssText = css;
        } else {
            // Other browsers
            createElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        } 
    });
```

I don't like this code because it overloads the page and it work slowly. How each time clear the style or just overload existing rules?

If there're any other way to reload css inside style?

Comment: You can add id to that style and later check if element with that id exists (in which case you should just overwrite it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need, it will change the `background-position` in runtime.

```
$(window).on('scroll touchmove', function(e) {
    var newposition = ($(document).scrollTop() * 0.4).toFixed(2);
    $('body').css('background-position', '0px ' + newposition + 'px');
});
```

Here is an [**example at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/3Cp3R/).

Comment: Thanks for answer, your code perfectly works for body animate but I need animate body :before & :after via javascript. It won't work within js code, I suppose that the one way to do this is to add it dynamically to document and then update. Maybe I'm not right and there're another way

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is someting like:

1. Create an array to keep track of all the rules and styles
2. Overwrite a certain rune in that array
3. "Publish"/create the style tag with a specific ID and overwrite it every time you need to

In my hones opinion parsing the text content of the of a style tag would be more complex and slower.